# DataGrid advanced cell editing (e.g. Fill, Copy, Paste)

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid, user-controls

I am working on a C# UWP application and have implemented a DataGrid into a page where I want the user to be able to enter metadata about uploaded files in bulk they will later upload to a server.

The DataGrid works, but I noticed that some features, like you would find in Excel, are not native. Specifically:

- "Fill" tool (e.g. take the current cell value and drag it up/down to populate other row values.
- Copy/Paste to cell/multiple cells (copy a cell value and paste to one or more others, without needing to enter the cell's Editing mode)

Does anyone know of any relevant libraries/extensions that could help here, or if there are none what the best way to start going about this would be?

There is probably some things I could do with custom code around events on the DataGrid, but I'd like to use something already out there if it exists. It seems that there is not an API to display Excel in the app (kind of like Excel Web App)

I did check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920251/drag-and-copy-for-wpf-datagrid), but this is for WPF DataGrid and some of the properties/functions aren't available (like SelectionUnit)
If nothing else works, my best workaround would be to export the data to a CSV, have the user enter the data in Excel, then reimport to the app - but that would also have some decent overhead to implement.

Comment: There is no such functions for the DataGrid control of the community toolkit. Maybe you could check the source code of the DataGrid -https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/rel/7.1.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid  and implement the feature by yourself. Or raise a feature request in the Community toolkit's github.

Comment: Or buy a third-party control.

Comment: Thanks @RoyLi-MSFT, I did raise a feature request since it seems like it'd be good for DataGrid long-term. But I know it probably won't be done when I need my project done though (if ever) so I'll keep looking around.